# October CMS: Despite the redirection, http://localhost/backend returns a 404, whereas http://localhost/index.php/backend works

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2, octobercms, octobercms-backend

I've installed Laravel October CMS. When I access http://localhost/index.php/backend, I can see the loging page of the backend. When I access http://localhost/backend I've 404 Not Found.

I've taken a look to `.htaccess`, I've uncommented the `RewriteBase` and set the value `/ /index.php`.

However it still returns a 404. Do you know why?

Comment: My first step in order to solve this will be to check if my htaccess file is working or not. You could check by putting some garbage lines in your htaccess file and try to access a URL if it gives 500 internal error then it means it works fine then we could move to next step and so on.

Comment: I have edited the `.htaccess`. I added `test` in first line. No error is shown so indeed the htaccess file is not read. :-(

Comment: You could go through this link https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/how-to-set-up-htaccess-on-apache/ once to enable htaccess, it was a quick Google check it out once, should be fine I believe,cheers.

Comment: So @RavinderSingh13 now it's correctly read and it overrides correctly Apache:) However I still have this issue

Comment: Yes @RavinderSingh13 I've already activated the htaccess, I simply forgot to do it haha , but ty

Comment: Ok, next step would be is index.php present in same/root path where htaccess is present? Else its obvious that you are getting 404.

Comment: Yes, `.htaccess` and `index.php` are under the same tree path:)

Comment: Please post the contents of your `.htaccess` file. It probably just needs a slight tweak, otherwise you need to explain precisely what it's meant to be doing. I would guess it needs to route all requests to the CMS front-controller. Is your "CMS" installed in the document-root?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are simply looking for following Rule based on your shown samples. Also please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^backend/?$ index.php [NC,L]
```

In case this is the only rule of your htaccess file then change `L` to `END` in above.

Comment: Mmh it's odd that I must rewrite `backend` this way no? October CMS doesn't contain the good rewrite rules?

Comment: @JarsOfJam-Scheduler, I am not sure on that CMS part but if you hit URL like `http:localhost:80/backend` then it will be served by index.php from behind the scene that's how we could do it in htaccess rules.

Comment: In fact, by default, Open CMS's index shows a link to `http:localhost/backend`. So it should be callable by default, without the need to add a `RewriteRule`. The line I've uncommented is a `RewriteBase` one because I thought the problem could be located at this line.

Comment: @JarsOfJam-Scheduler, also did you mean `http://localhost/index.php/backend` OR `http://localhost/backend/index.php` in your question?

Comment: `http://localhost/index.php/backend` works and redirects to `http://localhost/index.php/backend/backend/auth/signin` correctly. But the link that the CMS shows in th home page is just: `http://localhost/backend`. So I think I need to modify the base (so to use `RewriteBase`), no? (also I never spoke about `http://localhost/backend/index.php` that returns a 404 by the way)

Comment: @JarsOfJam-Scheduler, I am sorry I am not sure about CMS part if this doesn't help you and you don't want htaccess(which btw from your question looked like you needed) let me know then I will delete my answer then cheers

Comment: @JarsOfJam-Scheduler `RewriteBase` does not do anything by itself, it sets the default URL-path for other _relative_ substitution strings. So, basically, it depends on what other directives you have.

Comment: No pb @RavinderSingh13 , even if your answer didn't really solve my question, it's my bad: I didn't insist in the fact that my problem is actually bound to the CMS. However your answer is very good and relevant enough to solve the problem as I described it. So I've accepted your answer :D ! Thank you for your extremely appreciated help and happy new year to you and MrWhite :) Stay safe from cov19 ;-D !